# Why doesn't RazorViewEngine pick up my DisplayTemplate?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Application is an MVC3 application with RAZOR view engine.

Controller being used here is TestController.
I am using Nested Views.

Base view(Item Listing) goes like this,

```
//Listing.cshtml
@model ItemsList 
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Items[i], new { RowPosition = i})
}
```

here is the template for Item

```
//Item.cshtml
@model Item
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.HeaderText)
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x, "ItemDetails")
```

And here is the view for Item Details

```
//ItemDetails.cshtml
@model Item
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.Description)
```

So, I am trying to pass forward model from ITEM template to ITEMDETAILS template. ItemDetails.cshtml is placed under "Views\Test\DisplayTemplates". Infact i have tried placing it under folders "Views\Shared" as well as "Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates". But View engine seems just not to picking it up.

However Microsoft documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407429%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) states that view engine does look in Controller\DisplayTemplates folder to fetch the VIEW using TemplateName used.

Comment: It likely isn't a bug. Please write a more useful/relevant title.

Comment: Tom, my question is why view engine is not picking the View. The display for ItemDetails just shows blank. No Exception. How can i debug how view engine is working behind the scenes?

Comment: never underestimate the power of a good nap

Comment: I tried recreating this. If I specified "ItemDetails" in the base view then it would display the ItemDetails template instead of "Item" template correctly. If I specified "ItemDetails" within the "Item" template nothing happened, like you were mentioning. I don't know if this is a bug, but it was unexpected behavior.

Comment: We need the definition of Item and ItemsList

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be the intended behaviour for Display/EditorTemplates, presumably to prevent accidental infinite recursion in custom display templates, such as doing (in `Item.cshtml`):

```
@model Item
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x)
```

...which would infinitely display the `Item.cshtml` DisplayTemplate.

Obviously in your example you're passing the item/model to a *different* template, so it wouldn't cause infinite recursion. However, it still seems to get caught by the same safe-guard in the framework. Not really sure if it would be classified as a 'bug' or just 'by design'?

This is the check in the [DisplayFor/TemplateFor helper](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f59892797e46#src%2fSystem.Web.Mvc%2fHtml%2fTemplateHelpers.cs):

```
// Normally this shouldn't happen, unless someone writes their own custom Object templates which 
// don't check to make sure that the object hasn't already been displayed 
object visitedObjectsKey = metadata.Model ?? metadata.RealModelType;
if (html.ViewDataContainer.ViewData.TemplateInfo.VisitedObjects.Contains(visitedObjectsKey)) {    // DDB #224750 
    return String.Empty;
}
```

`ViewData.TemplateInfo.VisitedObjects` stores the visited objects/models for parent templates. When you run:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Items[i], new { RowPosition = i})
```

It renders your `Item.cshtml` DisplayTemplate and adds the item/model to `VisitedObjects`. This means when `Item.cshtml` tries to display another child template with the same item/model:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x, "ItemDetails")
```

The item/model is already in `VisitedObjects`, so the if statement above returns true and instead of rendering `ItemDetails.cshtml` it just silently returns/renders an empty string.

Comment: I encountered this "feature" recently and it caused me no end of consternation. I think that the MVC team made a mistake here. Returning an empty string gives the developer the impression that everything went fine, until they see the output. It also makes it next to impossible to figure out what _IS_ happening. At the very least the code could throw an exception, providing an explanation to the behavior and alerting the developer to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

try using `@Html.RenderPartial("ItemDetails", item)`

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use the for loop.  Display/EditorTemplates are capable of handling collections.

Second, what is ItemsList?  And how is it defined?  If it's just naming a particular collectiion type, then don't do that.  Just have a List or something instead (unless you need special item handling, in which case implement IEnumerable on your collection class).  You would then have an ItemsList.cshtml or simply an Item.cshtml if you convert to using a List

Also, your DisplayFor() in the main view is wrong.  you can't pass html attributes to DisplayTemplates that way.